# How can I tail -F a log file(truncate aware) in lua?

Tags: lua, tail, inotify

I'd like to make the output of `tailf` or `tail -F`, or something similar available to me in Lua without blocking or locking. If the file gets truncated or log rotated, the program will detect it and will return to the start. This seems to be a level 1 question but looks strange to me. I just can't figure it out. Does anyone could share some code?

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas come to mind, you can just pipe the output of `tail -F` directly into your script execution. From there you can just read it in from `stdin`. Perhaps something like this:

```
local c = 0
for line in io.stdin:lines() do
  c = c + 1
  print(c, line)
end
```

A problem with this is that `tail` uses `stderr` to report file truncation so the script won't see it unless you find some way to redirect `stderr` to `stdin`.

The other idea is to use `io.popen` and force the `stderr`->`stdin` redirection before the main loop. You can then use any standard pattern matcher to check for tail truncation.

```
local tailin = io.popen('tail -F '..(...)..' 2>&1', 'r')

local c = 0
for line in tailin:lines() do
  c = c + 1
  print(c, line)
  c = line:match 'truncated' and 0 or c
end
```

Note that both approaches are blocking btw.

Comment: I want to monitor log files in order to see new messages as soon they are enqueued. so it need to be non-blocking.

Comment: @ms2008vip You can just run this on a different terminal instance where blocking shouldn't matter.

Comment: hehe Thanks. Strictly speaking, the solutions you mentioned, only the first could be worked and the other is never. I'd prefer something more elegant like some kind of non-blocking read, or inotify.

Comment: In that case, you'll probably have to use an external library like luaposix. Lua itself doesn't provide any other facilities for doing this.